# how to move stellar lumens locally in the same node? like bitcoin-cli move

Tags: stellar-core, horizon

I am now making integrated API in my company exchange. Now, looking for "move" function in horizon.

Is there any command like the below?

```
bitcoin-cli move "timotei" "akiko" 0.01 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the official ["Send and receive money"](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/transactions.html) guide. If you are using a shared account for all your customers, you'll need to track account balance records in your internal database.

[Here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/anchor/index.html) you'll find a description of basic concepts. You said that you are implementing an integration with your exchange, so take a look at recommended [guidelines for anchors and exchnages](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/tree/master/ecosystem).